# after installing seaborn, import fails to find it

Tags: macos, python-2.7, anaconda, seaborn

I've tried installing `seaborn` under `anaconda` on my `mac`. I've tried following many different instructions.

It installs with no problem but "**import seaborn**" fails.

I'm using `Python 2.7` here. It will work for me under `Python 3` but unfortunately I'm taking a course in which the notebooks are `Python 2.7`.

```
import seaborn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-085c0287ecb5> in <module>()
----> 1 import seaborn

ImportError: No module named seaborn
```

Comment: The issue might be due to anaconda installing seaborn in python3.X. Try this in that case 1.  `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda` 2. `source activate py27` . After this install all required packages.

Comment: I've already tried that but to be fair to your comment, i did this again using exactly what you suggested and the result is the same.